# how to find subsequent tags in selenium for a particular tag

Tags: selenium

I'm trying to click on 'Recommended' input tag of a 'Samsung' label. Please find the appropriate HTML code below.
`

```
<div class="card-wrapper">
<a class="card-focus has-shadow" href="/app/72292">
<div class="card-container">
<div class="card-logo">
<section class="card-info">
<div class="card-name">Samsung Push Service</div>
<div class="card-publisher hidden-xs">Samsung Push Service</div>
</section>
<div class="card-rating">
</div>
</a>
</div>
<div class="hidden-xs">
<div>
<div class="app-management">
<div class="checkbox ">
<div class="checkbox ">
<label>
<input id="Recommended-72292" class="" aria-disabled="false" value="Recommended" type="checkbox"/>
<span class="cr"/>
<span class="layer-label">Recommended</span>
</label>
</div>
<a href="/mdm">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>`
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your input seems to be a checkbox, not a button. Try changing its `checked` value instead of triggering a click:

```
document.getElementById('Recommended-72292').checked = true;
```

Comment: Thanks @mika, i agree..But there are around 4 elements and each element have 'Recommended' element. I specifically want to check the Recommended for 'Samsung Push Service'.

Comment: First of all, IDs should be unique. If you're using classes you could use `querySelectorAll` instead of `getElementById` like this: `document.querySelectorAll('.samsumg-container #Recommended')`

Answer (score 0):

In selenium, click() method would do your job.

> ```
> if ( !driver.findElement(By.id("Recommended-72292")).isSelected() ) 
> {
>     driver.findElement(By.id("Recommended-72292")).click();
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

try following:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.checkbox input#Recommended-72292")).click();
```